# OnPageChange in Render pagination calling handlePageClick in page load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, pagination

I am new to React js, my React **pagination**, calling **handlePageClick** when page load. It should get triggered when user click only.

Below is my code

```
export default class Time extends Component {
constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.state = {
         selectedIndex: -1,

        page: 0,
        links: null,
        meta: null,
    };

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}

handlePageClick (data){
      this.fetchData(data.selected); // will call API to load data
}

renderPaginator() {
    const { page, meta, links } = this.state;

    return links.prev || links.next ? (
        <ReactPaginate
            initialPage={page}
            previousLabel={'Prev'}
            nextLabel={'Next'}
            breakLabel={'...'}
            breakClassName={'break-me'}
            pageCount={meta.last_page}
            marginPagesDisplayed={2}
            pageRangeDisplayed={3}
            onPageChange={this.handlePageClick}
            containerClassName={'pagination'}
            subContainerClassName={'pages pagination'}
            activeClassName={'active'}
        />
    ) : null;
}

renderTT() {
    const { meta } = this.state;

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div className="table-responsive">
                <table className="table table-responsive table-hover table-condensed ts-listing">
                    <thead>
                        {this.renderHeadings()}
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {this.renderRows()}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                {meta ? this.renderPaginator(Array(meta.last_page).fill(0), this.handlePageClick) : null} 
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
}
```

I have tried:

```
onPageChange={e => this.handlePageClick(e)}
```

Nothing is working. the **onPageChange** is still calling **handlePageClick**  when page load.When I commented out **onPageChange**, handlePageClick is not called, so the problem is in **onPageChange**?

Comment: how can page change without user clicking it

Comment: yeah, I am confuse..when my page load, i can see the handlePageClick is called and load data from api. so this onPageChange is trigerring, but without user click..

Comment: If I put any function in onPageChange, the function will get called without user click

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an open issue about this in [react-paginate](https://github.com/AdeleD/react-paginate/issues/152) . Please refer to it as for your full understanding. I will make it short here.

Just remove `initialPage={page}` from you code, because this is the line that invoke your callback handler

Comment: Or even better, don't. Instead, add `disableInitialCallback={true}`, as per the issue you linked.

If you remove the `initialPage` prop, you can no longer highlight the current page (active link).